# "Integrate SDK into Application" doesn't work

Tags: dji-sdk

I am trying to run the [Mobile SDK tutorial](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-integrate.html#android-studio-project-integration) and I think I did everything correctly as directed.

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dji.importsdkdemo"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions{
        doNotStrip "*/*/libdjivideo.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libSDKRelativeJNI.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFlyForbid.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libduml_vision_bokeh.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libyuv2.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libGroudStation.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFRCorkscrew.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libUpgradeVerify.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFR.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libDJIFlySafeCore.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libdjifs_jni.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libsfjni.so"
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation('com.dji:dji-sdk:4.11.1')
    compileOnly('com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.11.1')
}
```

This is the manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dji.importsdkdemo">

    <!-- Permissions and features -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory"
        android:required="true" />

    <!-- Permissions and features -->

    <application
        android:name=".MApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <!-- DJI SDK -->
        <uses-library android:name="com.android.future.usb.accessory" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.dji.sdk.API_KEY"
            android:value="my app key" />
        <activity
            android:name="dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJIAoaControllerActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter" />
        </activity>
        <service android:name="dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJIGlobalService" >
        </service>
        <!-- DJI SDK -->

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My errors:

```
error: cannot find symbol class BaseProduct 
error: cannot find symbol class Handler 
error: cannot find symbol class List    
error: cannot find symbol class AtomicBoolean   
error: cannot find symbol class NonNull 
error: cannot find symbol class NonNull 
error: cannot find symbol class ArrayList   
error: cannot find symbol class AtomicBoolean   
error: package Build does not exist 
error: package Build does not exist 
error: cannot find symbol class Handler 
error: cannot find symbol variable Looper   
error: cannot find symbol variable ContextCompat    
error: cannot find symbol variable PackageManager   
error: package Build does not exist 
error: package Build does not exist 
error: cannot find symbol variable ActivityCompat   
error: cannot find symbol variable PackageManager   
error: package DJISDKManager does not exist 
error: cannot find symbol variable DJISDKManager    
error: cannot find symbol variable AsyncTask    
error: cannot find symbol class Intent  
error: cannot find symbol class Intent  
error: cannot find symbol class Handler 
error: cannot find symbol class Handler 
error: cannot find symbol variable Looper   
error: cannot find symbol variable Toast    
error: cannot find symbol variable Toast
```

Sync project with grade files is running. If i try to make the project i get a lot of errors and the build failed. The java compiler cannot find many symbol classes or the package build doesn't exist and so on. 
Have i done something wrong or do i have to add or change something on my own? I am still a beginner and have been trying to solve the problem for days.

Maybe someone can help me here.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you appear to be missing the SDK key.  This is required in order to grant you access to use the SDK.  Without it any SDK calls will fail.

You need to log into your DJI developer account and create a key.

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.dji.sdk.API_KEY"
            android:value="my app key" />
```